# Angular 6 project and wamp server can't access the project from other computer on the same network

Tags: angular, localhost, wamp, angular6, wampserver

I am using wampserver as a local server for my angular application.

I've built my application using `ng build --prod --aot` command. Then I took the `dist` folder and put inside a virtual host on wamp called `angular.local` having the following script in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName angular
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/angular"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/angular/">
        #Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        #AllowOverride All
        #Require local
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from 192.168.0.140
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `192.168.0.140` is the network IP address of the user's laptop where we are going to access the application from.

On the servers `system32` hosts file, I've added the following line:

```
192.168.0.109 angular.local
::1 angular.local
```

Where `192.168.0.109` is the server's IP address.

When the user try to access the application using the link:

http://192.168.0.109/angular/

we can see the title of the application on google chrome tab title, but with 3 errors at the console:

[image]

Where thr runtime, styles and main java script files are not found.

I checked them on the servers angular folder and they do exist.

I did the same as mentioned [in this link](https://john-dugan.com/access-wamp-from-lan-computers/).

I have the .htaccess present within project folder.

I can access the localhost page using `http://192.168.0.109/`.

I tried using the following link but it didn't work:

> http://angular.local/

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing APache by using APache 2.2 syntax and Apache 2.4 syntax. So stick to Apache 2.4 syntax.

Also you ServerName should be `ServerName angular.local`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName angular.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/angular"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/angular/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.0.140
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And another VH for `dev.local` so assuming its in a folder called `dev` under `www`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/dev"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/dev/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.0.140
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to allow from any ip in the local network then us instead of the one above

```
Require ip 192.168.0
```

You will also have to add the domain name to the HOST file on the Other pc(s) like this, assuming WAMPServer is running on ip 192.168.0.10

```
192.168.0.10 angular.local
192.168.0.10 dev.local
```

Comment: I've done everything here, but still the same errors.

Comment: I amended the answer when I noticed you app domain was `angular.local`

Comment: Did you change the hosts file on the other PC?

Comment: @riggssfolly it worked and I can open the site, but when I tried to login, I had an error at the console saying:

Comment: `http://dev.local/scripts/login.php ERR_REFUSED_CONNECTION polyfills.js`

Comment: the angular script is on angular.local while the php server script is on dev.local

Comment: Then it sounds like you need another Virtual Host defined for `dev.local` in the server PC and also an entry in the HOSTS file of the other PC(s) to tell it where that site lives

Comment: my project is based on 2 virtual hosts, the first is where my angular dist folder, and the `dev.local` is where I am adding my server side scripts for login and other

Comment: I added a new line in the hosts file of system/drivers/etc for dev.local having the same server ip address and done. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName servername.com
 DocumentRoot path/to/dist

 <Directory "path/to/dist">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
 #   Require local
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I am having same angular application, built with ng build and added dist folder to apache2 and above is my **vhosts.conf** file. Working perfectly for me.

Comment: Still can't read the main, runtime and styles javascript files.